# How can i remove word from string?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$arr =array("Raven Lexy","rajesh123","xw2z","lolaurita","Artin");
$arrfind= Array
(
    [0] => Ohh... Perfect! You got lucky lolaurita 
    [1] => I just logged in... didn't have to make a new profile same one is stilol here whoot whoot! lolArtin 
    [2] => Hey babe, so what do you think? Have you come across any bugs? We 40 pages of bugs we are fixing which should be done in a couple of weeks, than the real marketing starts :)  
);
```

I have to match the above $arr with each index of $arrfind and return the remaining string will get like this.

```
$arrfind [0]=>Ohh... Perfect! You got lucky 
[1]=>I just logged in... didn't have to make a new profile same one is stilol here whoot whoot! lol
[2]=>Hey babe, so what do you think? Have you come across any bugs? We 40 pages of bugs we are fixing which should be done in a couple of weeks, than the real marketing starts :)
```

How can i do this 
please help,
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace), which accepts arrays as an arguement. In your case:

```
str_replace( $arr, "", $arrFind );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result = str_replace($arr, '', $arrfind);
?>
```